# ¿Cómo agregar librerías de Python un Procesamiento?

Tags: python, python-3.x, processing

Necesito trabajo en Python usando [Processing](https://processing.org/), pero no he podido agregar librerías de Python tales como `Image`, la pregunta es **¿Hay alguna forma de agregar las librerías de Python en `Processing`?.**

Intenté agregar la carpeta de la librería en el proyecto de `Processing` e importarla, pero me surgió este error.

```
processing.app.SketchException: Maybe there's an unclosed paren or quote mark somewhere before this line?
at jycessing.mode.run.SketchRunner.convertPythonSketchError(Unknown Source)
at jycessing.mode.run.SketchRunner.lambda$startSketch$3(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Por supuesto no falta ningún paréntesis o unas comillas sin cerrar, pues mi código es simple.

```
from PIL import Image

def setup():
  size(500,500)

def draw():
  if mousePressed:
     fill(0)
  else:
     fill(255)
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80,80)
```